# FlatBuffers Data Add Overlay

Tags: flatbuffers

I'm making a chat program using a `flat buffer`.
I want to move four ball variables.
ex) `value1 = true, value2 = false, value3 = true, value = false,`

The schema name of Flatbuffers is ServerInfo.

```
(i = 0; i  < 3; i++)
ServerInfo.AddValue(fb, value [i]);
```

I wrote this code.
A total of four values should be added, but only one was added.

The result I want) true, false, true, false.
Actual Results ) true, true, true, true

The ServerInfo value.value portion of the `test [i]` was the same as the `value [0]`.
How can we put it together once?

> Definition of ServerInfo.AddValue.

```
public static space addValue (FlatBufferBufferBufferBufferBufferBuilder) {builder.AddBool(4, Value, false); }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are setting the same scalar field 4 times. Not sure what language you're doing this in, but that should result in an `assert`. If you want to store 4 values, replace `bool` in your schema with `[bool]`.

I am guessing you're coming from Protobuf and expecting each field to be `repeated`?

Comment: The language I use is C#. Can I use Continues ServerInfo.AddValue? Can I continue to add values without using [bool]?